# Faking logins with Laravel Auth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

On our service there's admins and other users. I'm using the basic Laravel Auth package for handling registrations, logins etc.

What would be the best way to implement a feature, where an admin user could "fake login" as a regular user, without knowing the actual user's password?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work:

```
Auth::loginUsingId($userId, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a function in laravel `Auth::loginUsingId()`:

```
if(Auth::loginUsingId($userId))
{
    return redirect('/dashboard');
}
```

by which user can login by using its `id` in user table only. In this there is no need to pass `email`, `password` etc